# PdfBox-Android giving NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, pdfbox

A few months ago, I was using "compile 'org.apache:pdfbox-android:1.8.9.0'" in gradle and PdfBox-Android was working properly. I got involved in other modules of the app I am working on, and didn't use this part of the app.

Now when I tried to use it, I got a NoClassDefFoundError. A little searching around and I realised I had to change the gradle to "compile 'com.tom_roush:pdfbox-android:1.8.9.1'", which I did.

But it is still not working -

1. I am still getting a NoClassDefFoundError.
2. PdfBox-Android is based on PdfBox v1.8.9, whereas the latest version of PdfBox is 1.8.13. Could this be a reason?
3. On the main page of PdfBox-Android, it is mentioned that it "depends on the following libraries: SpongyCastle core, prov, and pkiv: ". However, when I visit the SpongyCastle page on github, I cant find any pkiv library, only pkix library.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it just saying "NoClassDefFoundError"? Nothing more? Or is the full exception message + stack trace confidential?

Comment: This is what I get - 

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.tom_roush.pdfbox.util.PDFBoxResourceLoader